# Piping up with rebus # 24

Tags: rebus

This is a 1-word verb, much shunned by messy folk.

[image]

Comment: i had a question, what do you use to create these rebus puzzles?

Comment: For some things, you have to draw it yourself; for most of them, tho, you use google.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm guessing it is

> Organize! (organ, eyes)